# Firebase Cloud Messaging - Change default Chrome icon for web notifications on Android

Tags: firebase, web-notifications

In `firebase` cloud messaging web notifications,
the default icon is chrome icon shown as a grey circle 
how can i change it [image: this]

Answer (score 3):

You cannot remove that small Chrome icon. It is present to make it clear that the notifications are delivered through the Chrome app.

**Update**: on some OS, including Android, you can now set the `badge` when you display the notification. You can [try that option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification) and see if it works in your case (here's a [blog post](https://blog.pushpad.xyz/2022/04/change-the-default-chrome-icon-for-notifications/) that I wrote about the icon / badge).

Comment: Any update about this issue? Is there an official reference that shows this fact? @collimarco